# MapKit Entitlements Oddity

Tags: mapkit, osx-mavericks, code-signing-entitlements

I have a simple Mac app, not intended for distribution of any kind; simply personal use. The app is an `NSWindow` which contains an `MKMapView`. As I don't have a Mac dev account, and don't want one (see "personal use only"), I'm not doing any form of code signing or provisioning.

However, on launch, I get a blank map and this error:

> Your Application has attempted to access the Map Kit API. You cannot access this API without an entitlement. You may receive an entitlement from the Mac Developer Program for use by you only with your Mac App Store Apps. For more information about Apple's Mac Developer Program, please visit developer.apple.com.

Do I really need to buy a Mac developer account just to use `MKMapView` on OS X? If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do. MapKit is restricted to App Store apps only, regardless of content usage.

Comment: That's asine, but I suppose it's out of our hands. Thanks!

Comment: It's quite ridiculous... You can use `MKMapView` on iOS without an entitlement, why not on a Mac? :(

Comment: If I turn signing off ( selecting  "none" in the  Identity section ), and then add mapkit framework, I can run the app. However, I get the target message in Xcode, clearly saying I need to ask for the entitlement :  "Your Application has attempted to access the Map Kit API. You cannot access this API without an entitlement. You may receive an entitlement from the Mac Developer Program for use by you only with your Mac App Store Apps. For more information about Apple's Mac Developer Program, please visit developer.apple.com.". The map view is opening, but it does not show the location required