# Can I use Mapkit through xcode for OSX 10.9 on an Enterprise developer license.

Tags: xcode, macos, mapkit

I want to develop a Mac app on OSX 10.9 which is not going on the app store. It will always be connected to network but only used internally within our business. I have an enterprise developer license. I have heard that mapkit development must go on the app store? Please can somebody clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would Apple not let you use MapKit for private use? Pretty sure it should be okay, but you might want to read through the terms for your developers license.

Comment: Hi - the reason I was asking was because I stumbled across this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987470/mapkit-entitlements-oddity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MapKit exactly in the **same way** like when creating app for app store submission. The only difference in enterprise program is that you cannot upload your app to the app store. From developer/api perspective there is no difference.