# Error after building and launching Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mapkit

I get the following error after building and launching my app. I haven't been able to track down what is causing it but everything runs fine. I am using MapKit and not sure if that is causing it.

```
Connection error while checking Apple Internalness. Error: Error
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with
a helper application." (The connection to service named 
com.apple.CrashReporterSupportHelper was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x608000279540 
{NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named 
com.apple.CrashReporterSupportHelper was invalidated.}
```

Comment: My thought was entitlements, but it appears you [straight-up need a dev account.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987470/mapkit-entitlements-oddity)

Comment: I do have a dev account and the app is approved and on the app store. It just annoys me when i am trying to debug i always get the same error before what i want to see.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error when a window that uses MapKit appears.  I'm also fully registered/entitled.  Did you figure anything out?

Comment: No, just ignoring it for now. Doesn't cause any problem. There was someone else in Apple dev forums with the same issue.

Comment: Please file a bug report: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @davecom I also get this when trying to run a modal sheet that contains an `MKMapView`. Did anyone resolve this yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a developers account and thats all setup and running then it could be to do with the `(The connection to service named 
com.apple.CrashReporterSupportHelper was invalidated.)` bit. Try filing a a bug report but also try reseting that from the Xcode preferences as that might help. I had a similar error once and when I rebooted Xcode the next day it was gone so hopefully thats just the case with that.